# How to start minimized program from linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux

How can I start a program from linux terminal that will be minimized on start? Is there any command for that?

edit: xfce + thunar
In background or minimized, any option is good enough.

Comment: What do you mean by "minimized"?

Comment: If it's about GUI windows, then you should specify your desktop environment and window manager. Please [edit] the question and add this information.

Comment: Also, do you know the difference between minimized and backgrounded - ie what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `In background or minimized` – Still unclear. E.g. you can run VLC in background from the shell point of view (`vlc &`) and its window will normally pop up on the desktop. Or you can run it as a foreground process while its window is not shown at all (with `xpra` or so). Does the program in question even display a GUI window? or is it purely textual (like `cat`)?